# Richfaces: How to change the rich:select behaviour for values not in list?

Tags: jsf-2, drop-down-menu, richfaces

I've got a question regarding the rich:select component.

For the following steps I've used the second example at the RichFaces showcases for rich:select: http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=select&skin=blueSky

Have a look at the following image to reproduce the components behaviour: [All steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfWBn.png)

If I enter a value that is not in the list (like "aaaaaaa"), the component looks like in the picture Step 1.
As you can see, the component stops reducing the list, after entering the second "a".
If I now select an item ("Alabama" in this example), click in the input box and start typing again, it looks like at the picure Step 2a.
Even if I clear the input-content and enter new values that are not in the list, the input is red and the list with the available items is empty: Step 2b

**Now my question: How can I achieve this behaviour from the very beginning (Step 1)?**

It looks like there is a little bug in this component too: 
If I delete the last "a" at the second example it looks like at Step 3a.
As you can see, the value is still red and the list is empty, even the value is now valid.
If I delete the last "a" again, everything is allright again: Step 3b

**Is there a way to correct this behaviour?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems solved with Richfaces v4.5.16: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-14254